# Can't detect wireless connections with an Atheros AR2413 on an Acer Aspire 3630

Tags: 11.10, wireless, ath5k

This is a new installation of Ubuntu 11.10 on an acer aspire 3630. The cd drive is broken so I had to install Ubuntu over network (and I suspect it did not install all the packages in the normal installation).

The problem is that ubuntu does not list the available wireless connections and I can't manually connect to my home wifi. I have tried a lot of things and this is all the info I have:

The wireless card is an AR2413.

The physical button to switch on/off the wireless does not work.

I am using the ath5k driver.

During boot I get the following message:

```
ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
```

**iwconfig**

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bg  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
```

**lshw**

```
*-network:1
   description: Wireless interface
   product: AR2413 802.11bg NIC
   vendor: Atheros Communications Inc.
   physical id: b
   bus info: pci@0000:00:0b.0
   logical name: wlan0
   version: 01
   serial: 00:16:ce:17:eb:4c
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath5k driverversion=3.0.0-12-generic firmware=N/A latency=168 link=no maxlatency=28 mingnt=10 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bg
   resources: irq:17 memory:e2010000-e201ffff
```

**rfkill list all**

```
rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

**UPDATE**

I discovered that the problem is that, when I boot Ubuntu the wireless is disabled. If I manually enable it it works perfectly... Until the next time I restart the computer. These are the commands I use to enable the wireless card:

```
sudo rmmod -f ath5k
sudo rfkill unblock all
sudo modprobe ath5k
```

Comment: That is not the problem; read the update.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to add those commands listed in your update, to /etc/rc.local to have them run at start up.

Comment: The commands require the super user password, so I don't know what would happen if I add them to the rc.local file.

Comment: commands run from /etc/rc.local are run as root as a part of booting.

Answer (score 0):

Speculative answer:

There is an old [bug-report on launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/568090), with the last update saying that this issue occurred in Natty.  Maybe this still hasn't been resolved in Oneiric.

Solution was:

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/modprobe.conf
```

add to the bottom of the file:

```
options ath5k nohwcrypt
```

Save and reboot.